# Is there something uniquely for JPG files so I can consiredier duplicates

Tags: c#, winforms, duplicates, photo, photo-gallery

I want to make sample WinForm C# app for hunting duplicate photos on my laptop.
My question is is there some record, tag ,Exif data or anything else which is unique for JPG(photo) file.
So I can read that data put into data set and hunt for duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could say Exif data is unique. This table gives you a good resume of what to get from Exif Data:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format#Example

Look at this project, sure the code will help you:

http://jpegdata.codeplex.com/

In this [stackoveflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017/what-is-the-best-exif-library-for-net), there is a good answer to get Exif data:

"If you're compiling against v3 of the Framework (or later), then you can load the images using the BitmapSource class, which exposes the EXIF metadata through the Metadata property"

Nevertheless, I would compare name and date, and it must be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the checksum for the file? create a hashtable for all the files you have scanned with the checksum as the key

Answer (score 1):

I would just compare the properties and if they all match then hash the contents and compare.

Comment: Properties of file ? Are they same even if is file copied from SD in different time intervals

Comment: It depends on the program you use, but Windows does preserve the date times.

Answer (score 1):

You could read in the pictures byte by byte and compare them. If they don't match stop reading.

Something like this. It's pretty vague but you'll get the idea.

```
while (match && !end)
{
    b1 = getnexctbytefromfilefirstfile();
    b2 = getnextbytefromfilesecondfile();

    if(b1 != b2)
    {
        match = false;
    }

    if(b1 == null || b2 == null)
    {
        end = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the hashing route, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3483184/4086).